# php html remove button to delete a MySQL row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to delete a MySQL row being displayed on a page. Yes, I want to delete the entry from the database.

I have tried several of the solutions noted throughout these forms and other google related searches for what I am trying to accomplish.

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
//  Display information from table & add remove button
$servername = "";
$username = "website";
$password = "";
$dbname = "website";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT location, thelink, status FROM main_page";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table align=\"center\"><tr><th align=\"center\">Image</th><th align=\"center\">Information</th></tr><br />";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td><img src=".$row["location"]. "><br /></td><td align=\"center\"><br /> ".$row["status"]. "<br /><br /><a href=\"delete.php\">Delete</a></td></tr>";


    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

When I try to add the $row variable to the end of the delete.php line it either doesn't show up or the page won't load because of an error.

Comment: You might want to edit out the credentials.

Comment: Show the error, improve your question.

Comment: Link to HTTP 500 error when using
    "<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo row['id']; ?>">Delete</a>"

[link]https://ibb.co/js5zGQ[/link]

Comment: Link to problem when using
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table align=\"center\"><tr><th align=\"center\">Image</th><th align=\"center\">Information</th></tr><br />";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td><img src=".$row["location"]. "><br /></td><td align=\"center\"><br /> ".$row["status"]. "<br /><br /><a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "\">Delete</a></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

https://ibb.co/k3Yx35
Note the circled link at the bottom left, there is nothing after the "id="
@CarlosAlexandre

Answer (score 0):

At the link do

```
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo row['id']; ?>">Delete</a>
```

Now on the delete.php do

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
$id=$_GET["id"];
// HERE YOU CAN MAKE QUERY TO DELETE THE RECORD
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt.  This method results in the page not loading (ie. HTTP 500 Error).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass through the ID for each row into the link to delete itself:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table align=\"center\"><tr><th align=\"center\">Image</th><th align=\"center\">Information</th></tr><br />";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td><img src=".$row["location"]. "><br /></td><td align=\"center\"><br /> ".$row["status"]. "<br /><br /><a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "\">Delete</a></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Then on `delete.php` you would need to check the ID based on the `id` $_GET parameter:

```
// Connection needs to be defined again -- ideally from an include()
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(isset($_GET["id"])){
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM table WHERE ID = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET["id"]));
  $stmt->execute(); 
  $stmt->close();
}
```

Keep in mind that this is incredibly dangerous to do a deletion through a $_GET request, as someone could simply visit `delete.php?id=1` through their browser and delete a given record; you'll probably want to incorporate $_POST into your deletions.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for the attempt.  This method results in the link being empty after the delete.php?id=

FYI.  This link is behind a password protected directory.